# Rails: Can I apply Ajax to a link_to method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

As I understand it, Ajax allows you to only refresh the part of the page that you specify, as opposed to reloading the whole thing. Is there a way of doing this with a link_to method, for example, `<%= link_to 'approve', approve_model_path(@model.id), method: :put %>`  ? I can't figure out how a link_to could be executed without the whole page being reloaded.

Comment: Same stuff `turbolinks` do? It's in Rails' template project, as fas as I remember, you might have even used it without knowing it. It works by pushing only the `<body>` of the AJAX-loaded page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply ajax by setting remote to true:

```
<%= link_to 'approve', approve_model_path(@model.id), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

This does a js request, then you need an approve.js.erb to do the few changes you need (without refreshing the page)